# App Engine deployment wont boot instance VM, reporting inconsistent version counts in the logs

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, deployment

I am having trouble deploying an App Engine service, and apart from the apparent cause that [the region is out of resources](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED), I have noticed an inconsistency between what the Versions / Instances pages in the console say, and what the logs say regarding the number of instances.

The problem is there are no instances running in the current version 20220211t141828, and when I deploy a new version it also cannot start any instances.

But the weird thing is in the logs it reports the number of instances going from 2 -> 4 then back to 2. However there are no instances running.
e.g. here I deploy version 20220312t164136 and the /previous/ version changes strangely. Even though the previous version has no instances running!

```
2022-03-12 16:46:17.272 GMT appengine.googleapis.com …appengine.v1.Versions.CreateVersion
…ta/services/app/versions/20220312t164136 audit_log, method: "google.appengine.v1.Versions.CreateVersion", principal_email: xxx

2022-03-12 16:49:35.779 GMT The number of running VMs for version 20220211t141828 changed from 2 to 1
2022-03-12 16:49:42.792 GMT The number of running VMs for version 20220211t141828 changed from 1 to 3
2022-03-12 16:49:51.181 GMT The number of running VMs for version 20220211t141828 changed from 3 to 4
2022-03-12 16:49:55.829 GMT The number of running VMs for version 20220211t141828 changed from 4 to 2
```

Does anyone know if this could be the cause of my inability to deploy? (instead of the resource pool exhaustion).

I did have two old instances for the previous version stuck in restarting, and I killed them off. It seems like the numbers the auto-scaler is using are off by 2.

Is there some way to "reset" the auto-scheduler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another activity log I'd not seen before which seems to explain this. Although there are no logs from my service/instance/code booting, I can see that the VM creation jobs are starting and stopping, both from my manually triggered deployments, and also from the auto-scaler working in the background.

So I presume the above numbers, 1-4 are counting the hopeful instance counts when the job starts, but the instances are not registered or listed in the instance page yet.

The Activity page is under Home > Activity menu, I'd never noticed it before or perhaps it's new, but it's really useful (so are the Recommendations)

[image]

So to answer my last question, no this behaviour was not the cause of the inability to deploy - that was caused by the zone exhaustion, and these figures are probably normal.

The zone seemed to have enough resources after 18 hours and an instance automatically started (although I'm still seeing failures on 2nd, 3rd instances so it's still not actually scaling but at least the site isn't entirely down.)